# Facebook's PHP SDK with custom login page instead of redirecting?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, authentication, sdk

Is it possible to create a custom login page to use with facebook's PHP/JavaScript SDK? I'm developing a web app and it doesn't seem very user-friendly to redirect the user to the facebook page to login. For example, once you hit login it doesn't even let the user know its loading, just sits there until it logs in.

I was wondering if it's possible to use ajax or cURL to log the user into facebook through a form within my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, you have to use Facebook's OAuth protocol.

Have you tried their [javascript solution](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/)? This does not take the user away from the page, but instead opens a popup which is less of an intrusion on the page.

Comment: I'm attempting to embed the app within a wrapper on Android. It's more of a hybrid and a popup doesn't work well. But thanks for the help! Considering security I did think it might not be possible, but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

The facebook api is just for you to obtain access credentials from their system. I do not know and until then I never saw no way to get credentials and log into facebook without the facebook api.